# Intune Autopilot replace WDS or Sccm

Tags: azure, microsoft-intune, endpoint

I have been doing some research on Intune autopilot - I see that once hardware hash is registered it can go on autopilot mode wherein- users just need to sign in and all configurations are taken care by Autopilot Profiles. One thing that stuck in mind is, can it replace WDS or SCCM where it can install OS with Autopilot?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Autopilot does not technically install OS using pre-defined OS image like WDS/SCCM does. It actually uses local device image and configures it out-of-the-box.
So Windows Autopilot is a NextGen replacement of WDS/SCCM, but for **Windows 10 installations only**. If you need to use a custom image, you have to use WDS/SCCM as before (or any other third-party alternative)

Comment: I always recommend my colleagues to watch the videos at https://www.youtube.com/intunetraining because they explain exactly what you refer to as "NextGen".